# google chrome extension - document.body is null in popup js file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I started out with hello world application from google documentation to write a chrome extension. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

I simply modified the popup.js to be:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "<b>blah</b>";
alert(document.head);
alert(document.body);
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

I expect this to display "blah" in my popup but I am getting document.body as null. I am new to js and chrome and my trying to figure out whats going on here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the closing script tag is encontered, the corresponding code is directly evaluated.

Since `background.js` is loaded in the head, `<body>` does not exist (yet). Hence, `document.body` is `null`.

Comment: I did think about that, but then how does it work for the hello world example that google has? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted/popup.js

Comment: @grasaved That extension initializes a `XMLHttpRequest`. This **asynchronously** fetches a resource from a server. Since the request is **asynchronous**, it is non-blocking. As a result, the page continues loading during the AJAX request. When the request finishes, the function is called. The `<body>` has already been created at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The DOM does not exist yet when the popup script runs. You need to listen to a `DOMContentLoaded` event in your popup script.

Something like this would work:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    console.log(document.body);
  });
```